# How to count occurrences of 15 numbers that are in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm new to writing code. I need to make a program that reads in 15 numbers into an array that are between 0-50 and then print the occurrences. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Occurrence
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int [] nmberchck = new nmberchck[50];
      int[] numbs = new int[15];
      System.out.println("Enter 15 numbers that are between 0 and 50 ");
      System.out.println();
      numbs[0] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[1] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[2] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[3] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[4] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[5] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[6] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[7] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[8] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[9] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[10] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[11] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[12] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[13] = scan.nextInt();
      numbs[14] = scan.nextInt();
      for (int nmb = 0; nmb < numbs.length; nmb++)
```

Thank you

Comment: So what's the question/problem you are having?

Comment: If you know the number range (min/max), you can create a second array which matches that range.  Loop through the first array and use the value as the index into the second array, incrementing the value at the specified index.

Comment: I just dont know how to setup the second loop according to the first loop if that makes sense. I get confused with loops.

Comment: Question: what about loops do you find confusing? Not trying to be condescending, just wondering which concepts you might be missing so people can help you learn.

Comment: So what I know about the first loop is that i'm checking what numbers were put into the array. I don't understand how to get the second loop to count the occurrences. So I don't know how the second loop needs to be formatted in order to count occurrences by giving it the first loop. I know this seems basic but i'm just a little confused and frustrated that I haven't been able to find a direct answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something. Are you trying to keep a count of the numbers entered? Or are you relying on the user to enter the correct amount of numbers? why do you need to count the occurrences if you already know you have 15 numbers?

Comment: If the user enters 3 and then enters the number 3 again I want the program to print that the number 3 was entered 2 times.

Comment: Oh, okay. Do you need to keep a count of each re-occurrence? Or just a total?

Comment: Program needs to just print out the total about of times that it  was inputted.

Comment: You can just use a nested for loop where the first loop iterates through the numbers entered and the second loop compares the index of the number it's currently looking at to the entire array.

Comment: @educoolguy could you please check my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: @educoolguy I apologize for the confusion. I deleted my answer since it is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### More Simple Version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nmberchck = new int[51];
        int[] numbs = new int[15];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 15 numbers that are between 0 and 50 ");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            numbs[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            if (!(numbs[i] < 0 || numbs[i] > 50))
                nmberchck[numbs[i]]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nmberchck.length; i++)
            if (nmberchck[i] > 0)
                System.out.println(i + " occured " + nmberchck[i]
                        + " times");
    }
```

### More Fun Version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> x = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> m = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        int tmp = sc.nextInt();
        if (!x.containsKey(tmp))
            x.put(tmp, 1);
        else
            x.put(tmp, x.get(tmp) + 1);
        if (!m.contains(tmp))
            m.add(tmp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(m.get(i) + " occured " + x.get(m.get(i)) + " times");

}
```

This will print out the number of times each number occurred in increasing order. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to print the number of occurrences of each number that is typed in?

I don't know what your teacher has in mind, but you already have an array of 50 called nmberchck.  You could use this array to count up the number of occurrences of each number, since the numbers are between 0 and 50.  Though actually, if you are including the numbers 0 and 50, you really need an array of 51.

To start with there are 0 occurrences of each number.  So initially each element in nmberchck needs to be set to 0.  You can use a loop to do this.

Next you have to accept 15 numbers as input, and count each one using nmberchck.  Since you are doing the same thing 15 times, use a loop for it.

So there are two loops, one to initialize, and one read in a number and count it.

Are these two loops nested?  To answer that, understand how many repetitions you are doing.
First initializing nmberchck elements to 0: 51 repetitions.
Then getting input: 15 repetitions.
Total: 66 repetitions.

When the repetitions add like this, that is one loop following another.

A nested loop is one loop inside another, and in that case the repetitions multiply.

The next thing to do is print out the results.  Since the nmberchck contains your results, you will loop through it again.

When you are trying to write code, break up the solution to the problem into simple steps.  Try to quantify and understand how you yourself are solving it.  How would you solve this problem by hand?  You can't write the code until you understand that.

BTW, this is not the most efficient way to solve this problem, but it is a good introduction to arrays, loops, and indexing.  Most of the nmberchck elements will not be used since you are only typing in 15 numbers - nmberchck  is a sparsely populated array.